# UICollectionViewCells overlapping

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionView` to show data in my application. Now the problem is when I scroll the view, sometimes the cell position does not remain stable. They start overlapping on each other. I checked the value that I am providing in the below method. They are correct. Here is my code :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and I am using default layout,

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
```

one think i noticed that UICollectionViewCell is not resizing according to UICollectionView width
![uicollectionView cell overlapping][2]

And as you can see in attached image, the collection view background color(red color) does not go on the back of full `UICollectionViewCell`. Need some guidance on this.

Thanks.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Post *post=[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

LoungeUserPostCell *loungepostcell=(LoungeUserPostCell *)cell;

if (indexPath.row==1)
{
    loungepostcell.userPostedText.text=post.chat_msg;

    loungepostcell.lblPostTime.text=@"";
    loungepostcell.lblUsername.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid =%@", post.user_id];
}
else
{
    if (post.chat_img_medium !=nil || post.chat_img_full!=nil)
    {
        //            CGRect chat_msg_rect=CGRectFromString(post.chat_msg_rect);
        [loungepostcell willHaveImage:YES imageRect:CGRectMake(10, [post.height floatValue]-kPostImageHeight, kPostImageWidth, kPostImageHeight)];

        if (post.chat_img_medium!=nil) {
            [loungepostcell.userPostedImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.chat_img_medium] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"G-story.png"]];
        }
        else
            [loungepostcell.userPostedImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.chat_img_full] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"G-story.png"]];

    }
    else
    {
        [loungepostcell willHaveImage:NO imageRect:CGRectZero];
    }
    loungepostcell.userPostedText.text=post.chat_msg;
    loungepostcell.lblPostTime.text=[[[Shared instance]dateFormateForLosAngeles]stringFromDate:post.chat_time];
    loungepostcell.lblUsername.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", post.user_detail.user_name];
}


return cell;
```

}

[image]

Comment: can you show your cellForItemAtIndexPath method?

Comment: added code for cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: i belive this problem is due to some flow layout issue

Comment: have you implemented sizeForItemAtIndexPath method to provide size for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem is in the cell, I am adding whole view as a subview because I am using nib. I am doing it so because I want to use nib and `UICollectionViewCell` class too.

```
[self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoungeUserPostCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0]];

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       // Initialization code
       self.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

       [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoungeUserPostCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0]];

       [self onLoadAdjustments];
    }
    return self;
}
```

now I am registering it as nib in Collection view and use `- (void)awakeFromNib` method to make changes in nib.